# Measuring the actual blocking time of python socket recv() for receiving Ack after setting a timeout

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, time

I did not get expected result in the Retransmission delay computation. I have included the python code snippet below,

```
s.send(base64.b64encode(ciphertext))   
try:
s.settimeout(0.01)                                  
t = perf_counter()
print(s.recv(1024).decode('ascii'))  
t2 = perf_counter()                             
tt = round((t2-t)*1000,2)                   
print('Delay is:' ,tt)

except socket.timeout as e:                  
print(e)
```

Theoretically, tt has to be <=10ms (+1ms for print & decode) otherwise s.recv() has to throw exception. But getting values till 25 ms in debian operating system. Other methods like time(), process_time() also are not giving expected results.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: 10ms is pretty short for a network timeout. The OS may not work to that granularity.

Answer (score 0):

You're not timing the recv alone, you're timing that plus a print operation, which will take some time.  Try it without the print and see if that makes a difference.

This is not necessarily the problem, but it's a reasonable thing to try first.

Comment: Print operation along with decode takes around 1ms . So that won't be a problem.